# Слетел перевод строки "Add login with" на странице привязок соц. сетей

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, способы-входа

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/login-add

> [image: страница добавления привязки]

Строка: Add login with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ru.traducir.win/string/13492

> Добавить вход через $provider$